# How to set up MariaDB for tungsten replicator?

Tags: mariadb, tungsten-replicator

I am using MariaDB and below is my config file:

```
cat /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf 
....
binlog_format=row
server_id=12
sync_binlog = 100
binlog-row-image = full
binlog_cache_size = 16M
binlog_stmt_cache_size = 16M
```

BUT tpm install has error message like below:

```
ERROR >> 127_0_0_1 >> The MySQL datasource binlog_format must be set to 'ROW' 
for heterogenous replication. The MySQL configuration file does not include   
binlog_format=row (RowBasedBinaryLoggingCheck)
ERROR >> 127_0_0_1 >> The MySQL config file '/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf' does    
not include a value for server-id (MySQLApplierServerIDCheck) 
Check the file to ensure a value is given and that it is not commented out
```

Please help!

Comment: I've never seen `binlog*cache_size` set that high; does Tungsten require them?

Comment: Ditto for such a high value of `sync_binlog`.

Comment: What versions are you using in that topology?

Comment: Thanks for comment @RickJames, I has post a answer below. The problem is tungsten-replicator only check "/etc/my.cnf" for "binlog_format".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has sloved this problem by adding "--skip-validation-check=MySQLApplierServerIDCheck" option.
For mariaDB, tungsten-replicator looks in the main configuration file, not in the included ones.